# JUnit dependencies in an offline Gradle project

Tags: gradle, dependencies, build.gradle, offline, junit-jupiter

I'm building a minimal Gradle (Groovy) project and I want to test with JUnit Jupiter. I do not have access to the internet so I have to have all JUnit dependencies locally. When I build I get the following error:

```
> Task :test FAILED

UnknownClass.JUnit Jupiter > UnknownClass.initializationError FAILED
    org.junit.platform.commons.JUnitException at EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:153
        Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError at OpenTest4JAndJUnit4AwareThrowableCollector.java:38
            Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException at BuiltinClassLoader.java:581

UnknownClass.JUnit Jupiter FAILED
```

---

My build.gradle file looks like this:

```
plugins {
    id 'application'
    id 'java'
}

application {
    // Define the main class for the application.
    mainClass = 'HelloWorld'
}

dependencies {
    // Use JUnit Jupiter for testing.
    testImplementation files("lib/junit-jupiter-api-5.9.1.jar")
    testImplementation files("lib/apiguardian-api-1.1.2.jar")
    testImplementation files("lib/junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.1.jar")
    testImplementation files("lib/opentestj-1.2.0.jar")
    testImplementation files("lib/junit-jupiter-params-5.9.1.jar")
    testImplementation files("lib/junit-platform-launcher-1.9.1.jar")
    testImplementation files("lib/junit-platform-commons-1.9.1.jar")
    testImplementation files("lib/junit-platform-engine-1.9.1.jar")
}

test {
    // Use JUnit Platform for unit tests.
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

---

And my test looks like this:

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;


public class HelloWorldTest {


    @Test
    void testTest(){ 
        assertEquals(0, 0);
        
    }

}
```

I tried switching out different versions of the libraries and adding some that could be needed. I'm not sure which libraries i need to execute JUnit tests with Gradle.